# what does this events error mean

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, c#-3.0

I have desktop application that have web service reference, in some cases it crash giving those errors in the system event log of client machine

> **1000**
>
> Faulting application xxxxxxxx.exe, version 1.0.0.14, 
>   stamp 4ef30030, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3625, stamp
>   4e154c98, debug? 0, fault address 0x000a20c6.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>
> **1023**
>
> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A0BC59E) (80131506)
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

the webservice designed using .NET 3.5 so it hosted under 2.0.5 framework on the IIS 7, the server is windows server standard 2008 service pack 2

any idea to solve this issue

Comment: Try to look at event log of System and Application . IS there any error related to .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the hosting server, you could try re-installing the .net Framework version in this case version 2.

Here are two good Microsoft KB articles that could help.

[How to repair an existing installation of the.NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306160)

[How to manually remove and then reinstall the.NET Framework 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908077)